# Browse asp.net development server from usb attached itouch

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I can browse using the desktop browsers via ..localhost:54647/... and from windows mobile emulators via my gateway ..//192.168.0.199:54647/..., but neither method works from either my Android emulator or from a usb attached itouch.  I know I may have to run IIS locally but it's more convenient to run the development server from Visual Studio 2008.

I'm running Vista with latest service packs.

I'm developing a mobile app using ASP.Net MVC.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this StackOverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555058/accessing-asp-net-development-server-external-to-vm). To summarize: only running on the local interface is by design. IIS is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks, thought that might be it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and now I debug from VS 2010 with my web app running on my usb attached iTouch.  The solution was portforward.exe that forwards requests from the ASP.NET development server to local port 8080.

Can't remember which site I got it from but this one has it: http://www.quantumg.net/portforward.php.

I entered:  localport: 8080, remotehost: localhost, remote port: 50779 (the ASP.NET development server's port).

Hope this helps someone else...

Comment: Meant to mention that I press F% in vs which starts my desktop default browser and then I grab my itouch and run its safari browser.

Comment: Also, portforward.exe is from Spider-IT, www.Spider-IT.info.