# How to make WP8 emulator access ASP.NET debug server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to get the WP8 emulator to access a ASP.NET Development debug server I run on my pc?

WP8 Emulator runs inside Hyper-V and the debug server on my pc is therefore not accessible to the emulator, is it possible to do so it is?

Only solution I can come up with is create a IIS server on my machine and debug that, but its much easier running development server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't really "how to access the development server from the emulator", but "how to access the development server from a remote location". The emulator is 'just' another device connected to the network.

And for that, I can suggest a few links:

- http://blog.waynehartman.com/archive/2010/05/30/218.aspx
- [Is There a Way to Make Remote Calls to ASP.NET Development Web Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652777/is-there-a-way-to-make-remote-calls-to-asp-net-development-web-server)

Comment: I tried the soap application suggested here http://web.archive.org/web/20100926083848/http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/jimw/archive/2009/09/03/accessing-the-visual-studio-asp-net-development-server-from-iphone.aspx but I cant connect at all http://www.gratisimage.dk/image-5F0E_5092F526.jpg is this wrong?

Comment: @Mech0z Looks like that very same article has been updated for Windows 7: http://web.archive.org/web/20100925095856/http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/jimw/archive/2010/08/18/iphone-accessing-the-visual-studio-asp-net-development-server-windows-7-update.aspx It says that the old app isn't compatible, and suggest to use a tool called `SPI Port Forward` instead

Comment: Cool, will look at that tomorrow

Comment: Official MSDN doc on this is at [How to connect to a local web service from the Windows Phone 8 emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580(v=vs.105).aspx)