# Set Reverse proxy for Visual studio 2012

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2012, development-environment, reverse-proxy

I need to set reverse proxy for my development purpose. I can find many blogs on how to do it for IIS or apache. But that will be used during deployment. During development I am using Visual studio 2012. How can I set reverse proxy for visual studio development server? Or can I simply tell visual studio to use iis?

Comment: Did you have any luck with my answer?

Comment: Did the answer below work for you? If it did, you should mark it as the answer so that others can benefit from your question.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this using Fiddler2 [(see Fiddler download page)](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler). It says that Fiddler2 is built for .NET 2, but still I'm using a more recent version of .NET.

After installing Fiddler, I followed [the instructions for creating a FiddlerScript rule](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy#write-a-fiddlerscript-rule) to use Fiddler as a reverse proxy. To be clear, I did NOT create a DWORD in the registry or follow any of the other instructions... I only followed what's stated under "*Write a FiddlerScript Rule*".

When it came to adding the line to `CustomRules.js` (step 5) my line looked like this:

`if (oSession.host.toLowerCase() == "sto-lt-eov:8888") oSession.host = "localhost:52044";`

The `sto-lt-eov`-value I got from opening up Command Prompt and typing `ipconfig /all`. Your value for this will be under the listing `Host Name`, the very first line in the output you get. Make sure you type it in lowercase in the rule - at first I just copied it and pasted, which never caused a match in the .toLowerCase()-method.

My IIS (development server) runs on port `52044` but that changes periodically, so the downside is that I'll have to maintain that part of the rule as the port changes.

The result of this was that I am able to access the website running on IIS Development Server using an iPad running on the same WiFi.

PS. I did this with Squid before, running on a [blog post from Ashley Angell mentioned in another StackOverflow-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652777/is-there-a-way-to-make-remote-calls-to-asp-net-development-web-server) but when I came back to this issue Fiddler seemed like a more user friendly option. Squid is absolutely riddled with options and in my opinion has less accessible feedback than Fiddler does. I still realize the tremendous power that Squid possesses... I just needed the simple solution :)